# Sorting multiple dicts in python by value

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I'm trying to sort multiple dictionaries in Python in descending order.

```
highs = []
file_a = open("/home/victor/Documents/Python-3.5.1/W2_0@IAB.CSV")
def func():
    for line in file_a:
        from collections import OrderedDict
        s = {}
        (s['date'], s['open'], s['high'], s['low'], s['close'],    s['volume'], s['openinterest'], s['totalVolume'], s['totalOpenInterest']) = line.split(',')
    newlist = sorted(s.items(), key=lambda s: float(s[2]), reverse = True)

func()
file_a.close()
```

However, everytime I run it i get this error:

```
File "/home/victor/Documents/first project.py", line 8, in <lambda>
newlist = sorted(s.items(), key=lambda s: float(s[2]), reverse = True)
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

I am very new to Python. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `items()` gives you `tuple` objects that contain two elements. The highest index for such a `tuple` is `1`, not `2`.

Comment: How would I be able to sort the lines in the text file based on the value "high"?

Comment: `s` is a dictionary with string keys like `'date'`, `'open'`, and `'high'`, but you're trying to use a key with the numeric value `2` in `key` function passed to your `sorted()` call. You probably want `float(s['high'])`.

Comment: I tried that, but got this error: IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: can you provide al least two lines of csv file data so we be able to reproduce your problem?

Comment: Your code is overriding the same dictionary, s, for every line in the file - so you're only actually storing the last one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem your code has is that it iterates through the whole file repeatedly creating a dictionary object named `s`, but doesn't do anything with each of them before creating the next one (except the last, see below).

The error message is because after creating and ignoring all of these dictionaries, an attempt is made to sort the values in `s.items()`after the read loop doing this has completed. This means `s` will be left holding the last dictionary created (from the last line of the file). Regardless, `s.items()` is a copy of the dictionary’s list of (key, value) pairs, which might contain, say, something like:

```
[('volume', '300000'), ('high', '110'), ('low', '90') ('totalOpenInterest', '4.56'),
 ('date', '01/01/16'), ('close', '101'), ('openinterest', '.99'), ('open', '100'),
 ('totalVolume', '1000000')]
```

Since there are only two things in each item of this list — each of which has, somewhat confusingly, also been named the `s` *argument* of the `lambda` function — so the `float(s[2])` in your code raises an `IndexError` because `2` is greater than what the highest valid index of `1` for each of these pairs of values.

I think the code below correctly does what you're trying to accomplish. It first stores each of the `s` dictionaries created in a temporary list named `data`, and then sorts it by one of the values from each of them referenced by its key (`'high'`).

```
from operator import itemgetter

def func(filename):
    keys = ('date open high low close volume openinterest totalVolume '
            'totalOpenInterest').split()
    data = []
    with open(filename) as file_a:
        for line in file_a:
            s = dict(zip(keys, line.rstrip().split(',')))
            data.append(s)

    return sorted(data, key=lambda x: float(itemgetter('high')(x)), reverse=True)


filename = "/home/victor/Documents/Python-3.5.1/W2_0@IAB.CSV"
sorted_dicts = func(filename)
for d in sorted_dicts:
    print(d)
```

Answer (score 1):

Three problems, both around this line:

```
newlist = sorted(s.items(), key=lambda s: float(s[2]), reverse = True)
```

First, this is outside the loop, which means `s` is just the last line of the file; all the previous lines' data has been thrown away. Second, even if it had all the data, assigning to a new variable `newlist` doesn't do anything useful; you probably want to append to `highs` or something.

The error message you're seeing, however, is because `s.items` returns a list of pairs (two-element tuples): `[(key1, value1), (key2, value2), (key3, value3),...]`.  If you want to sort by the values, given a single tuple `s`, that's `s[1]`.  The key is `s[0]`.  `s[2]` doesn't exist; that would be the third element of the tuple, but there isn't one.

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually storing anything other than the last line in the file, as you overwrite the dictionary `s` each time. You need to store that dictionary in a list:

```
data = []
for line in file_a:
    s = {}
    (s['date'], s['open'], s['high'], s['low'], s['close'], s['volume'], s['openinterest'], s['totalVolume'], s['totalOpenInterest']) = line.split(',')
    data.append(s)
```

Then you can sort the list with:

```
newlist = sorted(data, key=lambda x: -float(x['high']))
```

(Note that in this example I'm using the negative value of `high` instead of using `reverse=True`).

You also shouldn't import `OrderedDict` *every* time round the loop!